# Error in conversion of command line commands into batch file

Tags: batch-file

When i run :

```
D:\practice\\build\armv7a\gcc\am335x\beaglebone\bootloader>make
```

from command prompt it works fine.

Now i want to convert the same command into batch file.So its like:

```
@echo off
echo comipling the files

D:\practice\\build\armv7a\gcc\am335x\beaglebone\bootloader>make

echo comipling done...
pause
```

saved the file `build.batch`

but when i click on this , it gives error:

```
**comipling the files
'D:\practice\\build\armv7a\gcc\am335x\beaglebone\bootloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
comipling done...
Press any key to continue . . .**
```

Why???

Answer (score 0):

```
                                 v..v  This is the program to execute
D:\practice\b ... ne\bootloader> make
^..............................^  
This is the command prompt
```

Your command prompt is showing where you are working, what is your current active directory, and should not be included in the batch file as part of the command.

The equivalent to your command line should be to first change the current active directory to the indicated folder and then execute the command

```dos
@echo off
    echo comipling the files

    Rem Change to the adecuated folder
    cd /d "D:\practice\build\armv7a\gcc\am335x\beaglebone\bootloader"

    Rem Now, execute the command
    make

    echo compiling done... 
    pause
```